# Can I solder a plug to the end of my irrigation system power supply?

Tags: power, transformer, ac, soldering, wiring

I got a new sprinkler head unit that only takes power input from a barrel plug, [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-Adapter-Power-Supply-RACHIO-Smart-Sprinkler-Controller-MKA-482401000-Adaptor-/292039990795) is an ebay listing for the transformer it came with. It's 24VAC AC/AC transformer.

Problem is my old head unit was wired with a power supply that had exposed wires to a screw terminal. I have no outlets near my sprinkler unit, and the power supply for the old unit is wired behind the walls. I confirmed that the power supplies are compatible, so I am going to connect the exposed wires to a plug for the new unit.

My only two concerns are:

1. I can only find "DC" plugs like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079R94L4J), I am going to try them, but does it matter is says they are "DC" when my transformer is AC/AC? It's probably a dumb question.
2. My old head unit had a screw terminal for ground, do I need to find a plug that takes a ground wire too, or should I ignore the ground wire in this case?

Comment: those plugs will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no necessity to use a soldering-type barrel connector.

The screw-terminal-type barrel connector may be used, provided it is compatible with the barrel socket on the new sprinkler head.

You may ground the new sprinkler head, should it be all-metal and has a screw where you can connect the ground wire.